# Horizontal radio's and FormValidation plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation-plugin

I'm having trouble implementing horizontal form validation nicely with the FormValidation plugin (http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/) I have looked through the documentation but have not found a solution. Vertical radios work fine. I have attached an example. The reason I would like to make use of horizontal radios would just be to save a bit of modal real estate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your radio buttons and label in one div with class name "**whaterver**"

then add below css

```
.whaterver small.help-desk{
    display:block;
}
```

try this code then run.

If you get not output as you want then place your html code here to give working url so we can understand and give proper solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please give us your HTML and CSS code from your horizontal radios, so we can give you a possible solution.

This example works for me:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" value="1">One
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" value="2">Two
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" value="3">Three
  </label>
</div>
```

[Here is an image from the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjq2T.png)